# Google Line Chart - Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the line chart API from Google Developers. [Link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

It gives me the error *Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string* when i try to plot the graph. I have looked at other solutions from stack overflow but still could not resolve it. Any advice?

```
<script>
   var myarray = [['variable x','variable y']];

   function addInputs () {
    myarray.push([xInput.value,yInput.value]);
    }

   function graphPlot () {
         google.setOnLoadCallback();
         console.log("Graph is plotted!");
         var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myarray);

         var options = {
          title: 'Linear Regression Chart',
          curveType: 'none',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

  //Button send in input values into the myArray.
  enterButton.addEventListener('click',addInputs);

  //Button plots the graph
  plotGraph.addEventListener('click',graphPlot);

</script>
```

Comment: My xInput and yInput are from textbox, of type of floating number. i.e 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by changing the text to float value.

```
myarray.push([parseFloat(xInput.value),parseFloat(yInput.value)]);
```

But my input inside the index.html is of type number. why does it take string value instead?

```
<html>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" id="xInput"/>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" id="yInput"/> 
</html>
```